# c# TFS Skip Locked Items On GetItems

Tags: c#, tfs

I have this code for getting the list of items from all my Team Projects

```
ItemSet items = vcs.GetItems(@Projpath, RecursionType.Full);

foreach (Item item in items.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("  Item: " + item.ServerItem.Substring(item.ServerItem.LastIndexOf('/') + 1));
    Console.WriteLine("  Size: " + item.ContentLength);
}
```

But whenever there is a locked folder/item on that certain team project the code gets stuck on `Getitems` line.

Is there a way to skip the Locked Items or exclude them from `GetItems`?

Comment: Actually, those locked files won't affect the `vcs.GetItems("$/AgileMttGreen/Main", RecursionType)` method. This method is used to get the items information from a server path. Even a file is locked, it could also get the object of it. That may be other reasons caused your issue. Please try another path to test if it works or using another machine?

Comment: If there's some error messages, please post them here.

Comment: I have tried waiting for the application and it has thrown this exception.

`+  $exception {"Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed: Item, Items, ItemSet, QueryItemsResult, QueryItemsResponse, Body, Envelope. Line 1, position 532."} System.Xml.XmlException`

Comment: To do troubleshooting for this issue, did you tried that if other path could work, you could test a path with less files under it. And what version of TFS assemblies and TFS version you use, please install the Nuget packages(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/14.102.0) and using the assemblies in it.